# Bash - syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: bash, if-statement, parameters, parameter-passing, argument-passing

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $# -eq '0' ]]
then
    var=command

    if [[ ${var} -eq '0' ]]
    then
        do something
    else
        do something else
    fi
fi

if [[ $# -eq '1' ]]
    usage;
fi

if [[ $# -eq '2' ]]
    if [[ "$1" != "-r" ]]
    then
        usage;
    fi
    if [[ "$2" =~ some_pattern ]]
    then
        do something
    else
        echo "Pattern is in an improper format. Please enter it as: correct_pattern, and try again"
        exit 1
    fi
    usage="Usage: meta_script.sh -r correct_pattern
    -r for reset is used to manually pass a parameter instead of using the default"
exit 1
fi
```

When I run this script, this is the error I get:

```
./meta_script.sh: line 31: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
./meta_script.sh: line 31: `fi'
```

In the first `if` statement where I'm checking if the number of parameters are equal to 1, I had put a `then`, but I got the same error as above, except with `then` instead of `fi`. It's almost as if no matter what I put and where, I get these errors and when I remove them to try and fix it, I get another bunch of similar errors. Please help me correct this script. Thanks!

Comment: You missed a `then` for `if [[ $# -eq '1' ]]` and `if [[ $# -eq '2' ]]`. Try http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thank you! I will try that and let you know. If that works, please make it an answer, and I will accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: @EtanReisner: It worked! I am getting another error now, but essentially, its not the same and it worked. Thanks! Can you help me with the error? It happens when I give it the wrong number of parameters. Instead of going to usage, it just exits. What might be happening? I will modify the code here to reflect the "working" code and hopefully you can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to the segment:

```
if [[ $# -eq '2' ]]
    if [[ "$1" != "-r" ]]
    then
```

you are missing the `then` for the first `if` statement. Putting that in should get you past that error:

```
if [[ $# -eq 2 ]] ; then
    if [[ "$1" != "-r" ]] ; then
```

You'll see I've put the `then` on the same line since it's a good habit to get into, realising that `if` and `then` always go together (same as `while` and `do`). It also allows you to see more lines of "useful" code on any given terminal :-)

I've also gotten rid of the useless quotes around `2` since `$#` always returns a numeric value. I'd advise sticking to using quotes just for strings.